# What is the nature of the trash directory on macOS?

Tags: backup, trash

The "trash" on macOS should be a directory (along with information on the place where the file was before it was sent to trash).

The question is, where is this directory? Can we write down its path?

Somehow, I could not find trash in my time machine backup. Is there a way to find it? After all, I don't see why we would be bothered to exclude the trash from backup - isn't it easier just to backup all files?

Comment: Trash is located in your home directory under `.Trash`.  It’s a hidden directory.  You can reference it with `$HOME/.Trash` or `~/.Trash`

Comment: What specifically are you looking for?  Trash on your Mac or on Time Machine?  I ask  because it’s not backed up by default.

Comment: Every drive & every account has its own Trash. The Finder presents a concatenation to the user.

Comment: @Thinkr Then what it could be?

Comment: @Allan I am trying to see if there is a way to include Trash in the backup.

Comment: First, confirm that it is excluded with the command `tmutil isexcluded $HOME/.Trash`.  You should get “Excluded”. Let me know.

Comment: @Allan Yes. What can I do to enable it?

Comment: Use the command `sudo tmutil removeexclusion -p $HOME/.Trash`.   That will remove the block TM has on that directory.  Let me know if that works and I’ll write up an answer.